# Android Nested JSON with GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm very new to JSON/GSON so I apologize if this is a very easy question. I've been trying to create nested JSON in Android using GSON.

Here's what I'm trying to create:

```
{"choice": {"question_id":"1", "answer_id":"2", "survey_id":"1"}}
```

However the output that is coming out with my Android code has parentheses around the inner braces and a lot of additional \'s:

```
{"choice":"{\"question_id\":\"1\",\"survey_id\":\"1\",\"answer_id\":\"1\"}"}
```

Here's how I'm generating the JSON:

```
Map<String, String> choice = new HashMap<String, String>();
        choice.put("question_id", "1");
        choice.put("answer_id", "1");
        choice.put("survey_id", "1");
        String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(choice, Map.class);

        Map<String, String> choices = new HashMap<String, String>();
        choices.put("choice", json);
        String jsonChoice = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(choices, Map.class);
        Log.i("JSON", "JSON is: " + jsonChoice);
```

Is there a better way to create a nested JSON object? Also do the back slashes actually do anything or are those ok? jsonlint.com says that the json is valid, but it doesn't seem to work when I use it to post to my server.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I found [Why does Gson.toJson serialize a generic field to an empty JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299669/why-does-gson-tojson-serialize-a-generic-field-to-an-empty-json-object) which mentions [serializing and deserializing generic types](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Gener). This points out that Map.class won't work as it's not parametrized, or rather the Gson doesn't know it's a Map. So here's my updated code:

```
Type listType = (Type) new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();

        Map<String, String> choice = new HashMap<String, String>();
        choice.put("question_id", "1");
        choice.put("answer_id", "1");
        choice.put("survey_id", "1");
        String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(choice, listType);

        Map<String, String> choices = new HashMap<String, String>();
        choices.put("choice", json);
        String jsonChoice = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(choices, listType);
        Log.i("JSON", "JSON is: " + jsonChoice);
```

But unfortunately that still gives the same JSON output as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried using Gson to create json object or decode json to javabean, and successfully get the result you want, Here is what I tried:

```
public class Choice {
    private ChoiceDetail choice;
    public Choice(ChoiceDetail choice) {
        super();
        this.choice = choice;
    }

}

class ChoiceDetail{
    private String question_id;
    private String answer_id;
    private String survey_id;
    public ChoiceDetail(String question_id, String answer_id, String survey_id) {
        super();
        this.question_id = question_id;
        this.answer_id = answer_id;
        this.survey_id = survey_id;
    }

}

public class TestGson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChoiceDetail detail = new ChoiceDetail("1","2","3");
        Choice choice = new Choice(detail);
        Gson g = new Gson();
        String json = g.toJson(choice);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

I've tested Gson about nested objects, nested lists, and it seems when you generate a json string from an Object, you won't need to anything more than new Gson().toJson(object).(Even when your object have nested List properties!) Only when you try to generate a List to Json, you need to use TypeToken.

In short, generating json String with Gson lib is like this:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(object or List<object>)
```

decoding json string to object is like this

For Object:

```
ModelA modela  = g.fromJson(json, ModelA.class);
```

For List:

```
List<ModelA> list = g.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<ModelA>>(){}.getType());
```

you can try this yourself in a JavaSE with Gson lib included. It's really easy to use!

Comment: You. Are. Amazing! I have been struggling with this for hours! That worked perfectly.