# How to serialise generic object using jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind

this is my class

```
public class Response<T> {
    private final T data;

    private final String error;
```

I can only change a class. Can `jackson` serialise it without configuring `objectMapper`?

EDIT:
I'm using this object as a method result parameter in spring mvc @RestController. And jackson's objectMapper.canSerialize(Response.class) returns false.

EDIT:
I've fixed it this way:

public class Response {

```
private T data;

private String error;

@JsonIgnore
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY
)
private Class<T> type;

...

@JsonIgnore
public Class<T> getType() {
    return type;
}
```

Comment: serialization won't be an issue. However deserialization might be, you need to use type reference like mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<Response<MyDataType>>() {});

Answer (score 1):

While serializing, I think there will not be an issue as `T data` is going to hold the object of some real object and libraries like Gson will be able to serialize them properly, but there can be an issue with deserialization due to the fact that it doesn't know in which type it has to be deserialized. For that, you may be required the pass the specific `Type` so that to tell the library in which type you are trying to deserialize.(Note: I have worked with mostly Gson hence answers are influenced by that)

Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7299718/1093333